# Two events for validation form and field validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I need to do two validations on a form:  Validation username and validation upon submitting the form.  I tried to use separate events:

```
$('form').submit( function( event ){
});

$('.username').blur( function(){
});
```

This way the events collide when the presses ENTER.  I tried other events instead of blur, but none worked correctly.

I came to the following conclusion:

```
$('form').on('submit focusout', function( event )
{
    if( event.type == 'focusout' )
    {
        alert( 'field validate' );
    }

    else if( event.type == 'submit' )
    {
        alert( 'form submit' );
    }
});
```

My form records 'submit' and 'focusOut'.  When submitting the form, the fields will be checked, and when the focusOut event, the field will be checked.  Is my solution is correct or is there another more practical way? I can not use a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$('form').on({
    focusout: function() {
        alert('field validate');
    },
    submit: {
        alert('form submit');
    }
});
```

visit : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/multiple-jquery-events-on-one-element-with-different-functions-and-target-select

Comment: true friend could not think that way. this is correct, no way: `submit: function() {` thank you

Comment: how to get the field value when focusOut event? `$(this).val()` dont work